# "App not active This app is not accessible right now and the app developer is aware of the issue" when I am trying to add facebook to freelancer.com

Tags: facebook, authentication, freelancer.com-api

I am trying to add `facebook` to `freelancer.com` but it didn't work saying:

> App not active This app is not accessible right now and the app developer is aware of the issue.

Why is this happening and what should be done?
I have searched for solutions but no reasonable answer was provided yet. Is this something related to my `facebook` account?

Comment: It is related to freelancer.com . They have to fix the problem.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer? Facing this issue currently